# Recreate encryption Keys in MS-SQL RDS instance on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, sql-server, amazon-rds, ssrs

We are running Microsoft SQL server Standard edition running on AWS RDS, We had recently upgraded from sqlserver-se version 14.00.3223.3.v1 to version 14.00.3281.6.v1 as per the recommendation. We had recently enabled SSRS on the RDS instance , a new feature added to SQL server RDS solution. But looks like post this upgrade, server encryption keys have changed. SSRS is not coming up with the error ->

`The feature: "Scale-out deployment" is not supported in this edition of Reporting Services. (rsOperationNotSupported)`

On a standalone SSRS instance, to fix this issue, I would just run this command -> `rskeymgmt -s` , but not sure how do this on the AWS RDS SSRS instance. Is there a proc that I can run on the SQL to accomplish this?

The AWS docs doesn't have any info on this (this is the documentation I had checked already - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/configuring-microsoft-sql-server-reporting-services-on-amazon-rds-for-sql-server/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this appears to have been AWS RDS bug, we had to disable SSRS, drop the SSRS databases and enable it again.

1. Remove SSRS from that option group
2. Execute below command to drop the ssrs DB -

   ```
   `exec msdb.dbo.rds_drop_ssrs_databases;`
   ```
3. Add the SSRS back to option group.

For some reason this took more than 40 mis to save the options, but it appears to have solved.